# Importing vue project into GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab

I am trying to push a local repository to gitlab.

My folder structure is like this:

/path/to/folder
       /app
      README.md

When I push it to gitlab, the app folder, which contains all of my source code, is imported as a single file (which I can't even open), with a strange name:

app@1c22672a

How can I push my folder to gitlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"app" directory is an independent git repository! you should add it as a submodule or use current repository for both of them.

More from git help:

> hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
>   hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
>   hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
>   hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
>   hint:
>   hint:     git submodule add  app
>   hint:
>   hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
>   hint: index with:
>   hint:
>   hint:     git rm --cached app
>   hint:
>   hint: See "git help submodule" for more information.

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new to git. I removed the `.git` folder from the app folder and thought that it was no longer under git control.  How do I use the current repository for app (It's just a folder to contain source files.

Comment: try: `git add app`